# Where is this on highway 24/highway 12 in Utah?

Tags: identify-this, national-parks, locate-this, utah

I have been trying to find out where exactly this location is. A Google maps marker or coordinates would be great.

[image: APPROACHINGCOLORADORIVERBRIDGE-vi]

Comment: After about 20 minutes of research, I actually believe it's not on those highways.  The terrain is all wrong, and in addition, the file name - approaching colorado river bridge - neither 24 or 12 go anywhere close to the river (ok, same state, but they never ever cross it).

Comment: I reckon it's actually a mistake on that site, I've found the same image on another site as well, but same name, and I reckon one copied the other.  Still, the place must exist somewhere...

Comment: Totally have found it, just give me a few minutes, lining up the shot

Comment: @MarkMayo :P I guess I should give up, this one is tough to find, I'm now exploring Utah through Google Street View

Comment: @vince, done, this was hard!

Comment: Living in the age of computers is not without its share of issues, but this, this is why I am happy to be alive, today.

Comment: @MarkMayo you're the man!! I was think I went all the way on 12 and 24 on google map street view. I am glad you found it!!!

Comment: @RegisteredUser haha, no worries, it was fun :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK, It's called the [Hite Crossing Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hite_Crossing_Bridge), and a [Street View shot is available at this link that best matches the angle you have](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@37.889552,-110.407602,3a,75y,82.8h,90t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sRRL_Aed2_mxU20TYFjW_3Q!2e0).  It confused me for a bit as yours is using a long lens, but you can 'walk' down the hill and confirm it's all the same rocks, and in your shot you can just make out the Hite Bridge in the background, which is certainly the one at the location I have found.  The photo is actually taken from a road west, looking down the canyon towards the bridge!

[Regular Google Maps link to the bridge](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@37.8898738,-110.3733126,15z)

The reason it's so hard to find is that **it's NOT on your Route 12/24, it's actually on UT-95**.  The site you reference has just used a picture from the state, but it's about 50 miles due east of Route 12, as the road crosses Glen Canyon, at the Hite Bridge.

Comment: Arh, I was just crossing this bridge with Google Street View!

Comment: @vince the clue for me was the name - Colorado River. I'd looked at all the street view shots around 12/24 and the terrain was wrong.  I then google image searched colorado river bridges until I saw the one that matched, then it was a case of figuring out which way they were driving from :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are a grand total of **three** road bridges over the Colorado River in Utah (this one, US-191 near Moab, and the Dewey Bridge on UT-128).  So maybe that would have helped.

Comment: @NateEldredge *eye twitch*